# copying google doc file in shared drive using c#

Tags: google-docs-api

We have been using google drive for a while now to select an existing doc, owned by one of our employees, copy it and then merge data into placeholder fields to then download a pdf version of the doc.  It's been working fine except now other employees want access to the created docs.  So when we give them a link, the original employee has to give them access.  We want to move the docs to a shared drive where all employees can see anything in the shared drive.  From what I could find in google on this, it looks like we need to set the SupportsAllDrives property to true on the request.  However, I can't find that property on any of the objects that we're creating when copying the base document.  Because of this I keep getting a 404 from google when trying to copy the file.  Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

```
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = GoogleCredentials.accesskey,
    ClientSecret = GoogleCredentials.secretkey
};

var refreshToken = _credService.GetRefreshToken();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
{
    throw new Exception("Missing google refresh token for google doc processor task.");
}

var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = refreshToken };

var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = secrets
}),
"user",
token);

var docService = new DocsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
    ApplicationName = "Contract Merge"
});

var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
    ApplicationName = "Contract Merge"
});

var newTitle = "Agreement for " + contract.FirstName + " " + contract.LastName + " " + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
var newFile = new google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File { Title = newTitle };
var documentCopyFile = driveService.Files.Copy(newFile, GoogleConstants.TemplateDocId).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the C# library reference, an optional query parameter like `supportsAllDrives` (see [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy#parameters) on the API docs) is handled by a property of the [CopyRequest class](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.CopyRequest.html#methods).

Therefore, after building the `CopyRequest`, but before executing it, you have to set the property `SupportsAllDrives` to `true`, as shown here:

```
FilesResource.CopyRequest copyRequest = driveService.Files.Copy(newFile, GoogleConstants.TemplateDocId);
copyRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
copyRequest.Execute();
```

#### Reference:

- [Class FilesResource.CopyRequest](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.CopyRequest.html#methods)